# What's the correct way to set up a plot in a bokeh (0.10) server session that I'm going to later update?

Tags: bokeh

I know that the Bokeh server is getting an overhaul soon but I need to set up a plot.  I have something like this in the Django view:

```
document = Document()
session.use_doc(name)
session.load_document(document)

if document.context.children:
    plot = document.context.children[0]
else:
    output_server(name)
    plot = figure(title="Crawler Monitor", tools="pan,wheel_zoom,resize,save,hover", x_axis_type="datetime",
                width=800, height=400)

document.add(plot)
session.store_document(document)
script = autoload_server(plot, session)
```

Then I have this in a corresponding Celery task:

```
    self.session.load_document(self.document)
    plot = self.document.context.children[0]

    plot.x_range.start = min_x
    plot.x_range.end = max_x
    plot.y_range.factors = active_urls

    plot.segment(active_x0, active_urls, active_x, active_urls,
                                          line_width=10, line_color="orange")
    self.document.add(plot)
    self.session.store_document(self.document)
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting a value error when trying to set the `x_range`:

`ValueError('expected a value of type float, int8, int16, int32, int64, int or long, got 2015-10-21T15:34:39.572000+0000 of type datetime64',)`

I didn't have this problem before when I manually initialized the `x_range` in the setup step.  Is this necessary?

Comment: You are using a datetime to set the range bounds while it's expecting a numerical value. You either use your workaround or convert min_x and max_x

Answer (score 0):

One workaround:

```
    # manually instantiate model
    plot.x_range = Range1d(min_x, max_x)
    plot.x_range.start = min_x
    plot.x_range.end = max_x
    # same here
    plot.y_range = FactorRange(*active_urls)
    plot.y_range.factors = active_urls
```

Is this a reasonable approach?